# Pandas delete rows where any column (but 2) does not match a regex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like that:

```
1   07.06.2022  06:55  <NA>      <NA>           3  <NA>   <NA>      5     5    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         6  <NA>  <NA>
2   07.06.2022  08:20  <NA>         6        <NA>  <NA>      6   <NA>  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         1  <NA>  <NA>
3   07.06.2022  13:00  <NA>      <NA>           2  <NA>      4      6     5       1      5   <NA>         2  <NA>  <NA>
4   08.06.2022  06:40  <NA>      <NA>           3  <NA>   <NA>      1     4    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         2  <NA>  <NA>
..         ...    ...   ...       ...         ...   ...    ...    ...   ...     ...    ...    ...       ...   ...   ...
79  20.07.2022  08:10  <NA>         2        <NA>  <NA>      5   <NA>  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    6.0         4     3  <NA>
80  20.07.2022  10:15  <NA>         2        <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         5  <NA>     3
81  20.07.2022  13:00  <NA>         2           6     5      5   <NA>   1-2    <NA>      6    3.0         3     5   1-1
82  20.07.2022  14:20  <NA>         2        <NA>  <NA>   <NA>   <NA>  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>    6.0         1     5  <NA>
83  21.07.2022  07:00     1      <NA>           6  <NA>   <NA>      4     5    <NA>   <NA>   <NA>         3  <NA>  <NA>
```

The first two columns are fix but after that there is no fix number of columns.
Sometimes a column of these additional columns contain invalid characters (NaN is valid!).

I try to delete those rows. But I don't know how.

I found the following solutions - but none of them matches my case:

##### `df[df["col"].str.contains("this string")==False]`

In that case I need to know which column contains that string (or does not contain). But I've no idea how many columns are available. I can iterate over them all but it feels not the right way.
But `contains` might work with regex.

##### `df[df.isin(...)`

This needs specific items that are contained. But I don't have a list of all valid possibilities.

##### df.eq(r'\d([-]\d)*')

I tried to do something like:

```
df = df[df.neq(0).any(1)]
```

for regexes but it's not supported.

##### Merging all columns to a new one

...and use the first approach to delete the rows. It is pretty easy to combine a fix number of columns:

```
df['new-col'] = df['col1'].str + df['col2'].str +
```

I tried

```
df['new-col'] = ''.join(df.columns[2:])
```

but that doesn't work.

##### What I have

The regex that should match for each `columns[2:]` is: `\d([-]\d)*` (or the value should be NaN)

Are there any Ideas to delete rows where any column match (or does not match - inverting the regex is pretty easy) a regex?

##### sample-data as CSV

```
Datum,Zeit,User1,User2,User3,User4,User5,User6,User7,User8,User9,User10,User11,User12,User13,User14
03.06.2022,10:45,,,,,,6,,5,,6,,,,
07.06.2022,06:55,,,3,,,5,5,,,,6,,,
07.06.2022,08:20,,6,,,6,,,,,,1,,,
07.06.2022,13:00,,,2,,4,6,5,1,5,,2,,,
08.06.2022,06:40,,,3,,,x,4,,,,2,,,
08.06.2022,12:55,,,3,5,,5,6,5,4,,4,,,
09.06.2022,07:00,4,,4,,,2,,,,,x,,,
09.06.2022,09:52,,2-4,,2-6,,2-4,,,,,2-1,,,
09.06.2022,13:00,,4,,2,6,1-2,,1-3,3,,1-5,3,,
10.06.2022,07:00,2,,3,,,3,,,5,,6,,,
10.06.2022,09:50,,4,,,,,,,,,1,,,
10.06.2022,11:00,,6,,,,2,,,,,,,,
13.06.2022,6:30,1,,,,,4,6,,,,,,,
13.06.2022,10:00,,6,,1,,,,,4,,,,,
13.06.2022,13:00,,6,,,,1,4,,5,,,,2,
14.06.2022,8:00,5,,,,,5,4,,,,,,,
15.06.2022,8:00,1,,,,,4,2,,3,,,,,
```

[online runnable sample](https://onecompiler.com/python/3ybb9vpgp)

This running sample contains all the code as string. But I try to read an xlsx-file containing the data an I don't want to do some tricks on the source data. A solution might be to export the xlsx to csv, load them into memory as string, run a regex to filter all lines and after that put it into pandas <- this sounds weird.

Comment: @mozway Yes sorry. You were a little too fast.

Comment: So to be clear, you want to delete the rows that contain a range `'a-b'` instead of a digit or NA?

Comment: @mozway I added a link to a runnable sample.

Comment: @mozway The User-Columns may contain a single digit, multiple digits separated by '-' or NA. But there is also an `x` that I don't want. Maybe there are any other characters. None of them is allowed but what matchs `^\d([-]\d)*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to delete rows that contain 'x' in columns other that the first two.

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[~df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda c: c.astype(str).str.contains('x')).any(1)]
```

*NB. for an exact match use `df.iloc[:, 2:].eq('x')` in place of `df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda c: c.astype(str).str.contains('x'))`*

output:

```
         Datum   Zeit  User1 User2  User3 User4  User5 User6  User7 User8  User9  User10 User11  User12  User13  User14
0   03.06.2022  10:45    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN     6    NaN     5    NaN     6.0    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   07.06.2022  06:55    NaN   NaN    3.0   NaN    NaN     5    5.0   NaN    NaN     NaN      6     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   07.06.2022  08:20    NaN     6    NaN   NaN    6.0   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN      1     NaN     NaN     NaN
3   07.06.2022  13:00    NaN   NaN    2.0   NaN    4.0     6    5.0     1    5.0     NaN      2     NaN     NaN     NaN
5   08.06.2022  12:55    NaN   NaN    3.0     5    NaN     5    6.0     5    4.0     NaN      4     NaN     NaN     NaN
7   09.06.2022  09:52    NaN   2-4    NaN   2-6    NaN   2-4    NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN    2-1     NaN     NaN     NaN
8   09.06.2022  13:00    NaN     4    NaN     2    6.0   1-2    NaN   1-3    3.0     NaN    1-5     3.0     NaN     NaN
9   10.06.2022  07:00    2.0   NaN    3.0   NaN    NaN     3    NaN   NaN    5.0     NaN      6     NaN     NaN     NaN
10  10.06.2022  09:50    NaN     4    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN      1     NaN     NaN     NaN
11  10.06.2022  11:00    NaN     6    NaN   NaN    NaN     2    NaN   NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
12  13.06.2022   6:30    1.0   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN     4    6.0   NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
13  13.06.2022  10:00    NaN     6    NaN     1    NaN   NaN    NaN   NaN    4.0     NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
14  13.06.2022  13:00    NaN     6    NaN   NaN    NaN     1    4.0   NaN    5.0     NaN    NaN     NaN     2.0     NaN
15  14.06.2022   8:00    5.0   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN     5    4.0   NaN    NaN     NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
16  15.06.2022   8:00    1.0   NaN    NaN   NaN    NaN     4    2.0   NaN    3.0     NaN    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

How it works:

```
# invert condition
~

# select all but first 2 columns
df.iloc[:, 2:]

# check if the values contain "x"
.apply(lambda c: c.astype(str).str.contains('x'))

# True is any value in row is True
.any(1)
```

##### updated answer

keep rows with all among (NAs, digits, regex), but not anything other than that:

```
# which cells contain ^\d(?:[-]\d)*$ ?
m1 = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda c: c.astype(str).str.contains('^\d(?:[-]\d)*$'))
# which cells are NA?
m2 = df.iloc[:, 2:].isna()
# which cells are numeric?
m3 = df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').notna()

# do ALL cells in a row match at least one of above?
mask = (m1|m2|m3).all(1)

# if True, keep the row
out = df[mask]
```

Comment: No. - Yes I want to delete columns containing an `x`. But there can be any string in a cell that I don't want. The `x`'s are samples. There could also be an unwanted `y` or `hello` or what else.

Comment: You can use a regex in `str.contains`, sorry then I don't get your issue, maybe provide a real-life example?

Comment: Yes I realized that I can use a regex in `contains`. Wait. I`m testing.

Comment: Hm. Nope: `df = df[df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda c: c.astype(str).str.contains(r'^\d([-]\d)*$')).any(1)]` But the x's are still there.

Comment: If I change `any` to `all` an empty dataframe is returned.

Comment: Normal, unless you have a row with all columns that are `a-b`. Note the important `~` in my answer.

Comment: It's a bit strange. `df = df[df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda c: c.astype(str).str.contains(r'x')).any(1)]` returns only lines that contain an `x`. If I change the pattern to `[x]` it is still working. But if I change the pattern to `[^\d.-]` it fails and the entire dataframe is empty.

Comment: but you want to **keep** the `^\d([-]\d)*$`, right?

Comment: See the update for my guess of what you want

Comment: _but you want to keep the `^\d([-]\d)*$`, right?_ <- YES!

Comment: But maybe I can live with contains `[^\d.-]` But that also doesn't work.

Comment: have you checked the updated part of the answer?

Comment: Yes I did. My fault. The first I did was `df = df.astype(str)` to convert all the data to string. If I remove it your answer works.

Comment: I'm still confused why `df = df[df.iloc[:, 2:].apply(lambda c: c.astype(str).str.fullmatch(r'\d([-]\d)*')).all(axis=1)]` isn't working. That's based on your idea - but doesn't work. [fullmatch](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.fullmatch.html)

Comment: Why don't you use masks as I detail, all the tiny parts are important. You can't get it to work with **one** comparison ;)

Comment: Year maybe.....

Comment: (Well you could… if you handle the NA/NaN as string, but its quite ugly)